# jQuery Ajax response variable from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I've got a simple question, but haven't been able to find the exact solution I need. How can I use a jQuery $.ajax to call a PHP file that just echos two PHP variables, and save them to javascript variables in the response?

Comment: Encode the data as JSON in PHP, send it as response, parse the JSON in JavaScript and use the data as you see fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you would do something like:

```
$.getJSON('ajax_responder.php', function(data){
        window.var1 = data.var1;
        window.var2 = data.var2;
});
```

and then in ajax_responder.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $var1 = 'foo';
    $var2 = 'bar';
    $data = array(
        'var1' => $var1,
        'var2' => $var2
    );
    echo(json_encode($data));
?>
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: thanks, this is just what I needed. I'm having a slight problem thought, in the php file I'd like to set $var1 and $var2 to two global vars that I set through a $_GET in a separate PHP file. when I try to access set $var1=$global1 its null, what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: if its a global variable try putting `global $global1;` somewhere in the code right before you use `$global1`

Comment: this is strange. if i include my ajax_responder.php in my index.php, it echos the correct json formatted data {"var1":"test","var2":"name"}, so I know it's echoing the two variables correctly.  but when I try to set window.test = data.var1, in the $.getJson response it comes up null

Comment: nevermind, i got it. the url wasn't being passed the correct variable so it was never being made a global var. thanks for the help!