# How to display a response from jQuery/ajax call in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have the following code that someone else helped me get:

```
function updateEpisodeSeen() {
    var anime_id = <? php echo $anime_id; ?> ;
    var anime_list_entry_id = <? php echo $anime_list_entry_id; ?> ;

    jQuery.post("/path_to_it/my_php_file.php", {
        firstParam: anime_id,
        secondParam: anime_list_entry_id
    }, function (data) {
        //this is your response data from serv
        console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
}
```

Now the .php file that is ran, I update some information and echo two variables out.

So in the `console.log(data);` those two variable values are shown properly. I am just wondering how I can show these values in my actual php code? Since these values are updated on the backend, I want to show the users their updated values on the front end as well. So if I could possibly set a php variable to those responses and then echo those instead, but php code isn't ran until a page refreshes so that might not be the way to go since I want the values to  update without the page refreshing.

Comment: You have to run another javascript code that updates the front end. So basicly you run this code you've posted here and after it finishes you use another code to update the front end values.

Comment: Okay, that's a start! How do I communicate with my previous code? Since that would hold the information about the response it got from my `my_php_file.php`. Also I am a complete newbie in jQuery/Ajax/Javascript

Comment: @user27899 put alert(console.log(data)); into your code and show me the result

Comment: @NathanSrivi when I put alert around the `console.log(data)` I get a popup from my site saying `undefined` however, in the javascript console log it shows the updated value of my variable that I echo out from `my_php_file.php`

Comment: ok what is your requirement. without page loading every minute Ajax loading . it is correct or wrong.

Comment: Basically, I want the value updated with the response that I get from my other php file without re-loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign the response to some PHP variable you can follow this

[jQuery Ajax response variable from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510997/jquery-ajax-response-variable-from-php)

if you want assign to a html variable you can do that using Jquery

```
 $('#ID OF FIELD').val(data.text);
```

or

```
 $('#ID OF FIELD').html(data.text);
```

Comment: If I assign it to a php variable that already had a value (meaning I am updating it with this value), it won't show the updated value until I refresh the page, since PHP is only ran on page reloads. If I need to go with HTML, how do I hide the original value and replace it with the updated value HTML value?